# Change a div element's class by its index using the noUiSlider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nouislider

I want to change div class when slide range UI. I couldn't

```
var behaviourSlider = document.getElementById('tap');

noUiSlider.create(behaviourSlider, {
  start: 2,
  step: 1,
  behaviour: 'drag',
  connect: [true, false],
  range: {
    'min': 1,
    'max': 4
  }
});
```

run https://jsfiddle.net/cnsvnc/evass2ef/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add event listeners for the [`start`/`end` events](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/).

Then inside of the event listener callbacks, you can call the `.add()`/`remove()` methods on [the `classList` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) in order to add/remove the class on your `.hometab` element:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/fqdwc0n7/)

```
var behaviourSlider = document.getElementById('tap');
var targetElement = document.querySelector('.hometab');

noUiSlider.create(behaviourSlider, {
  start: 2,
  step: 1,
  behaviour: 'drag',
  connect: [true, false],
  range: {
    'min': 1,
    'max': 6
  }
});

behaviourSlider.noUiSlider.on('start', function() {
  targetElement.classList.add('active');
});

behaviourSlider.noUiSlider.on('end', function() {
  targetElement.classList.remove('active');
});
```

Here is a snippet demonstrating this:

```js
var behaviourSlider = document.getElementById('tap');
var targetElement = document.querySelector('.hometab');

noUiSlider.create(behaviourSlider, {
  start: 2,
  step: 1,
  behaviour: 'drag',
  connect: [true, false],
  range: {
    'min': 1,
    'max': 6
  }
});

behaviourSlider.noUiSlider.on('start', function() {
  targetElement.classList.add('active');
});

behaviourSlider.noUiSlider.on('end', function() {
  targetElement.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
.hometab {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/9.2.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/9.2.0/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="tap"></div>

<div class="cloudhome">
  <ul class="hometab">
    <li><span>1</span> Core</li>
    <li><span>2</span> GB RAM</li>
    <li><span>20</span> GB HDD</li>
    <li><a data-balloon="Example" data-balloon-pos="up" href="#">Order Now</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Based on your comment below, if you want to show the corresponding `ul` element by its index based on the value of the slider, then you could use the following.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/rh79swwd/)

```
var behaviourSlider = document.getElementById('tap');
var targetElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hometab');

noUiSlider.create(behaviourSlider, {
  start: 0,
  step: 1,
  behaviour: 'drag',
  connect: [true, false],
  range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 3
  }
});

behaviourSlider.noUiSlider.on('slide', function() {
  var index = +behaviourSlider.noUiSlider.get();

  [].forEach.call(targetElements, function (element) {
    element.classList.remove('active');
  });

  targetElements[index].classList.add('active');
});
```

As you can see, the value of the slider is retrieved and converted to a number. Then there is a loop that hides all the target `ul` elements and shows the desired one based on the index (value of the slider).

Here is a snippet demonstrating this:

```js
var behaviourSlider = document.getElementById('tap');
var targetElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hometab');

noUiSlider.create(behaviourSlider, {
  start: 0,
  step: 1,
  behaviour: 'drag',
  connect: [true, false],
  range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 3
  }
});

behaviourSlider.noUiSlider.on('slide', function() {
  var index = +behaviourSlider.noUiSlider.get();
  
  [].forEach.call(targetElements, function (element) {
    element.classList.remove('active');
  });
  
  targetElements[index].classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
.hometab {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/9.2.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/9.2.0/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
<div id="tap"></div>

<div class="cloudhome">
  <ul class="hometab active">
    <li><span>1</span> Core</li>
    <li><span>2</span> GB RAM</li>
    <li><span>20</span> GB HDD</li>
    <li><a data-balloon="Example" data-balloon-pos="up" href="#">Order Now</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="hometab">
    <li><span>2</span> Core</li>
    <li><span>4</span> GB RAM</li>
    <li><span>40</span> GB HDD</li>
    <li><a data-balloon="Example" data-balloon-pos="up" href="#">Order Now</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="hometab">
    <li><span>4</span> Core</li>
    <li><span>6</span> GB RAM</li>
    <li><span>60</span> GB HDD</li>
    <li><a data-balloon="Example" data-balloon-pos="up" href="#">Order Now</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="hometab">
    <li><span>8</span> Core</li>
    <li><span>100</span> GB RAM</li>
    <li><span>100</span> GB HDD</li>
    <li><a data-balloon="Example" data-balloon-pos="up" href="#">Order Now</a></li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: Good answer. Note that there is also a `start` event which is more usable in this case than `slide`, as it is called only once.

Comment: thank you for answer but i want to change hometab class "active" when drag slide. I want to equal 4 steps with 4 ul. If it is 1 then 1 ul will be active. if 2 ... this is possible?

Comment: @Lg102 - Good point, updated, thanks. Also, thanks for creating noUiSlider! I have used it in many projects and it is by far the best slider out there!